# Can one sit in a Yogic posture (Asana) when not performing spiritual activities like meditation?

Tags: yoga, meditation, yoga-sutras, asana

Can one sit in an asana (e.g. half-lotus / full lotus) in a non-meditative context such as when using the computer / browsing the internet? Or is it an offense?

I tried to search online but found no articles covering this. Are there any rules as per the scriptures if it is allowed? I just would like to sit stably since I tend to slouch and get out of form with chairs (forward head, etc.) and would also like to use the time I take up with computer to spend conquering asanas.

Comment: Oh now understood the Q .. If u feel ok u can sit ... no instructions will be found in scriptures for ur query ..

Comment: I hv edited the title to make it clearer and now it matches with body's question.. previously it was somewhat misleading IMO. Feel free to edit again if needed.

Comment: No, it's not an offense since sitting in these positions is not only great for spiritual reasons, but they also have physical benefits such as great posture.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks a lot for the apt correction! Hmmm... what does conventional wisdom say though amongst Hindus regarding that? Or other 'acceptable' sources?

Comment: @Viper91 Thank you for the input. For now, I'll keep on doing it, until I know otherwise.
The Japanese seiza is very close to the Hindi Vajrasana, and the former is used in non-spiritual activities, so maybe it can be indeed used for daily tasks; doesn't mean though that I can use that for justification since they have different cultural contexts and their identicalness hasn't been established.